# How did Ei Sei's mother, the Queen Mother, escape/get rescued from Zhao?

Tags: kingdom

In the story of the manga,

> it is said that after Ei Sei escaped Zhao (and eventually rescued by Qin troops), the King became aware of his escape minutes right after they exited the last gate, sending Zhao's cavalry to search for him. Everyone but Sei died, and even then had to be rescued almost at the end of the way.
>  If they went through all this trouble to just get Ei Sei, it is only strongly implied that Sei's mother, who hadn't been rescued, would be in grave danger, probably geting killed some time soon (since Sei's Zhao pursuers at some point mentioned that it didn't matter if they captured Sei dead or alive), and if not heavily watched and/or tortured and disgraced more harshly that she had been before (since people's logic of those times was so flawed that they would go so far as to blame some innocent person from a nation for the crimes of some other person from the same nation).

Having said that, I am wondering **how the hell did she get out from Zhao?** (seeing as Sei's initially unnoticed escape was barely possible.)

But having read until chapter 185, yet another question arises in my head.

> If Sei and his mother hated each other so much (she tried to kill him), **why on earth was she rescued in the first place to begin with?** A thorough explanation on this would be great and would stop me from having to open a new question.

Aside from this, comes a question that might be considered off-topic, but I'll ask it anyway just in case. Is there any similar real life historic records chronicling how Lady Zhao somehow moved from Zhao to Qin?

I've done a quick read of Wikipedia and seem to not find anything, however I will keep on researching and update this if I find the answer on my own.

Comment: I Don't think this is answerd in the manga so far. All we know is that After Sei successfully escaped from Zhao at the age of eight and became the king of Qin, the queen mother was brought to the capital as well and became the head of the Royal Harem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Ryo Fui's ranked biography in *Shiji*, both the Queen Mother and Ei Sei were returned to Qin by Zhao even before Sei's father became king, though I think conflicting accounts were given in other biographies in *Shiji* as to when and how they got back to Qin, let alone other historical records. The mangaka didn't follow the canonical history closely (who the hell is this Hou Ken dude?) nor present the stories as logically, so the story of the manga *Kingdom* shouldn't be taken seriously.

Regardless of proper history,

> Remember that the Queen Mother is a Zhao woman and that after the escape of Ei Sei, an heir to the throne, there really is no point in keeping her as a hostage, and Ruo Fui could have bribed or persuaded the Zhao officials to send his lover the Queen Mother back anyways. In any case, Sei would still have rescued her because it would be against the norm and bad for his reputation to ditch the Queen Mother in poverty in Zhao*. By killing the Queen Mother, Zhao would gain nothing but give Qin a moral high ground in invading Zhao. If the explanation in this paragraph is confusing or misleading, forget about it and just take my words in the first paragraph for it.
>  <sup>* I think the mangaka screwed up here, because the [Queen Mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Zhao) was a daughter of a prominent family, thus was unlikely to have lived in that condition.</sup>

Comment: you sure revolutionized my small-chinese-history-knowledge world with this explanation. It sure cleared up a lot of things.

Comment: In the anime (sorry no time to check the manga), I remember a scene when Sei was on his way out of Chou (Zhao) when his rescuers mentioned that another team will work to rescue her.